# Cronjob for security updates?

Tags: 12.04, security, cron

I'm having trouble creating a cronjob for automatic security updates on my ubuntu server 12.04.

I separated the security sources into a different file, and then did this from within a cronjob:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
apt-get -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="security-sources.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" update -y
apt-get -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="security-sources.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" upgrade -y
```

But I'm getting all kind of weird messages in the log:

Example 1:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

Example 2:

```
Unpacking replacement python-apport ...
Preparing to replace apport 2.0.1-0ubuntu15 (using .../apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb) ...
stop: Job failed while stopping
invoke-rc.d: initscript apport, action "stop" failed.
```

Example 3:

```
Unpacking replacement dh-apparmor ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
```

After receiving these logs in my email inbox, I logged in via ssh and saw this:

```
44 packages can be updated.
24 updates are security updates.
```

So I guess it didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use `unattended-upgrades`? It is specifically designed to do just this.

Comment: @GerhardBurger But that won't let me choose the exact time when it happens. I don't want it to happen in a peak hour.

Comment: Partly true, it will make a job in the `cron.daily` if I am correct, but you can change when `cron.daily` runs by editing the `/etc/cronjob` file, see [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/135906/when-does-cron-daily-run) for more information. Apart from that, `unattended-upgrades` sleeps for a random interval so that not all users update at the same time, because then the servers would be crushed...

Comment: I put my comments and some additional information about automatic security updates into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer to your scripting problem, but I recommend using the [unattended-upgrades [image: Install unattended-upgrades]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unattended-upgrades) package. It is specifically designed to do just that. You don't have to worry about updating at a peak hour, because `unattended-upgrades` is run with a random delay (max 30 minutes) because otherwise the servers are being crushed.

If you still want to change the time your updates are done, it is useful to know that the `unattended-upgrades` is in `cron.daily`. You can change when `cron.daily` is executed by editing the `/etc/crontab` file, for more information see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/135906/when-does-cron-daily-run).

---

If you want more information about setting up automatic updates in general (including some pointers on how to write your own cron job) see [the Ubuntu help page on AutomaticSecurityUpdates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates).